# Replace the nth-from-end occurrence of string in each line

Tags: debian, text-processing, sed

Using sed, how can I replace the Nth to last occurrence of a character on each line of a given file?

In this case I want to replace the 3rd to last `;` with `,`

input

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9
10;20;30;40;50;60;70;80;90
100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900
```

expected output

```
1;2;3;4;5;6,7;8;9
10;20;30;40;50;60,70;80;90
100;200;300;400;500;600,700;800;900
```

I know I could replace the 6th occurrence like this

```
sed 's/;/,/6' input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

Or the last one

```
sed -r 's/(.*);/\1,/' input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

But in my particular case and because of some nuances, I need to start from the end.

I've tried something like

```
sed -r 's/(.*);/\1,/3' input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could explicitly capture two more delimited fields:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*);([^;]*;[^;]*;)/\1,\2/' input_file.csv
1;2;3;4;5;6,7;8;9
10;20;30;40;50;60,70;80;90
100;200;300;400;500;600,700;800;900
```

or more programatically

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*);(([^;]*;){2})/\1,\2/' input_file.csv
1;2;3;4;5;6,7;8;9
10;20;30;40;50;60,70;80;90
100;200;300;400;500;600,700;800;900
```

where the number in the quantifier `{n-1}` replaces the nth from last.

Answer (score 14):

You could simply reverse the lines, change the Nth occurrence, then re-reverse:

```
 rev file | sed 's/;/,/3' | rev
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `gawk`:

```
awk -F';' '{print gensub(";", ",", NF-3)}'
```

The `gawk` built-in function `gensub()` replaces nth to last semicolon with comma.

Answer (score 6):

`sed` is good when you're working with entire lines, but `awk` and `perl` are better when you need to work with fields/columns within a line.

```
$ perl -F';' -lane 'splice @F,-4,2,join(",",@F[-4..-3]); print join(";",@F)' input.csv 
1;2;3;4;5;6,7;8;9
10;20;30;40;50;60,70;80;90
100;200;300;400;500;600,700;800;900
```

This splits the line into the @F array, using `;` as the separator.  Then it replaces the fourth-last and third-last fields with a single string containing the values of both fields separated by a comma.

Then it prints the entire @F array with semi-colons as the field separator.

---

`splice` is perl's built-in general purpose array manipulation function.   There are several forms for using it, but the form I'm using here is:

```
splice ARRAY,OFFSET,LENGTH,LIST
```

i.e.

```
splice @F, -4, 2, join(",",@F[-4..-3])
```

- `ARRAY`: @F, perl's default array when used with `-F` or `-a` options, similar to awk's $1, $2, $3 field numbers.
- `OFFSET`: -4, the fourth last field
- `LENGTH`: 2, two fields (i.e. `$F[-4]` and `$F[-3]`)
- `LIST`: in this case the "LIST" has only a single element, a string containing the values of fields -4 and -3 joined by a comma.  In general, though, LIST can be an array of any length, so `splice` can also be used to insert more fields into an array.

See `perldoc -f splice` for details.

Also, `@F[-4..-3]` is what's known in perl as an array slice.  The range operator `..` returns the elements of fields -4 *through to* -3.   For this script, it could also have been written as `@F[-4,-3]`, which is the elements -4 *and* -3. Array slices can be specified with ranges and/or lists.

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU sed` we can do as follows.

- skip any further processing,print line, go back read next line if less than 3 semicolons in a line.
- change all semicolons to newlines.
- progressively revert the newlines one by one until we are left with 3 newlines.
- now change the first new line to comma and the rest reverted.

```
sed -e '
  s/;/&/3;T
  y/;/\n/

  :a;s/\n/&/4;tb
   s//,/;y/\n/;/
  :b;s//;/;ta
' file

1;2;3;4;5;6,7;8;9
10;20;30;40;50;60,70;80;90
100;200;300;400;500;600,700;800;900
```

---

With `Perl` we split and also record the field separators in the split up array (@F).
Then the 6th field from the end is the 3rd semicolon from the end and which we change to comma. Rest is unchanged.

```
perl -aF'(;)' -plse '
  $F[-6]=",",s/.*/@F/ if @F >= 6;
' -- -\"= ./file
```

---

Using POSIX awk, we modify the separators based on their position:

```
awk -F\; -v n=3 '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF-n?",":(i==NF?ORS:FS)) }' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on [steeldriver's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655554/116858) that anchors the pattern at the end of the line and therefore can use `3` (or whatever number, `n`, you need to use) rather than `2` (i.e. `n-1`) for the repeat count of trailing fields, as long as there are actually that many fields.  It also does not care about the initial data on the line, before the delimiter that we want to replace.

Using standard `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/;\(\([^;]*;\{0,1\}\)\{3\}\)$/,\1/' file
```

Using on extended regular expression in `sed` implementations that support it:

```bsh
sed -E 's/;(([^;]*;?){3})$/,\1/' file
```

Either expression match the last three fields.  The sub-expression `([^;]*;?)` will match a string that contains no `;` character, and then optionally ends with one such character.  The last field on the line does not end with a `;`, so this allows us to match that field and still anchor the full expression to  the end of the line.

This, like most `sed` solutions, would not work if any field contains *embedded* `;` characters or newlines (which are allowed in CSV files).

---

Using a CSV parser to convert the data into JSON, modifying it with `jq`, and then turning it back into a CSV file with the correct delimiters.  This would cope with data containing embedded delimiters, newlines, and quotes:

```bsh
csvjson -H -d ';' file |
jq -r --argjson n 3 '.[] | [.[]] | .[-($n+1):(if $n > 1 then -($n-1) else null end)]] |= [join(",")] | @csv' |
csvformat -H -D ';'
```

This uses `csvkit` to turn the CSV into JSON.  It then imports the value `3` into the `jq` variable `n` on the command line and uses it to join the two fields based on this value.  The modified data is then turned back into CSV and reformatted to use `;` as delimiters as from the start.

Given a CSV file with four columns and four rows, like

```
A;B;C;D
1;"2.1;2.2";3;4
1;2;"3.1
3.2
3.3";4
1;"And then I said ""2 2 2""";3;4
```

the second delimiter from the end is changed to a comma (effectively merging the 2nd and 3rd fields into a single field):

```
$ csvjson -H -d ';' file | jq -r --argjson n 2 '.[] | [.[]] | .[-($n+1):(if $n > 1 then -($n-1) else null end)] |= [join(",")] | @csv' | csvformat -D ';'
A;B,C;D
1;"2.1;2.2,3";4
1;"2,3.1
3.2
3.3";4
1;"And then I said ""2 2 2"",3";4
```

Comment: Note that this answer still replaces the `;` if less than `n` `;` exist. Try `echo "abc;def" | sed 's/;\(\([^;]*;\{0,1\}\)\{3\}\)$/,\1/'` which outputs `abc,def`.

Comment: @Isaac Yes it does, which is why I was very careful to add "as long as there are actually that many fields".  The second part of my answer does not behave in that way though, you'd be happy to hear, which is why I did not include that wording there.

Comment: @guest_7 Thanks for your contribution, but I would not answer with a GNU `sed` solution generally as I don't personally use GNU `sed`.  The code also lacked explanation.  You are free and most welcome to add that solution in your own answer though (which is already a GNU `sed` solution).

Comment: actually I was thinking of this `sed 's/;\(\([^;]*\(;\|$\)\)\{3\}\)$/,\1/'`

Comment: @Jasen You seem to be using GNU `sed`, right? That `\|` is an alternation, I believe, which `sed` ordinarily does not support in basic regular expressions. Isn't `(;|$)$` the same as `;?$`? I don't really use GNU `sed`, but if you find that this command works better, then by all means use that instead.

Comment: yes, I am ans wasn't aware that that was unavailable for you.

Comment: @Jasen Not unavailable. I just don't really use GNU `sed`.

Comment: But of course that `(a|b)` isn't the same as `(a?b?)`. The former must match either an a or an b, the later could just be empty and match nothing. Same mistake again. @Kusalananda

Comment: @Isaac Not really when the right hand side of the alternation is `$`.  What they showed was something to the effect of `(;|$)$`.  How would you rewrite that without using an alternation? I would rewrite it as `;?$`. It's absolutely true that `(a|b)` is not the same as `a?b?`, but what was shown was not `(a|b)`, was it? It was `(a|b)b`, i.e either `ab` or `bb`.  Since `b` was `$`, you get either `a$` or `$` (`$$` is the same as `$` in an extended regular expression), i.e. `a?$`.

Comment: @Isaac You could argue that the expression that Jasen showed was a basic regular expression and that `$$` therefore matches a `$` at the end of a line, but then again, alternations are not available in basic regular expressions so any discussion about that would probably assume that one is using GNU `sed`, which I'm not doing. Or, you could rewrite their `\(;\|$\)` as `\([;$]\)`, but then it's just nonsense and no longer related to the data in the question at all.

Comment: There isn't such thing as an equivalent to an alternation in BRE. **Obsolete (``basic'') regular expressions differ in several respects.  '|' is an ordinary character and there is no equivalent for its functionality.** [From Freebsd re_format manual](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/7/re_format/). Directly from the horse mouth. @Kusalananda

Comment: I understand that from your perception you either have to use extended regexes (which do not have **back references**, and you need back references to use the `\1` in the replacement part os the sed `s///` command) or basic regexes. That is the way that your choice of `sed` works. But thinking that an alternation is equivalent to an optional match (`a?`) is fundamentally wrong and leads to other mistakes. @Kusalananda

Comment: Please read [A good explanation of alternation in BRE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62944/can-posix-bre-express-all-regular-languages)

Comment: So, no, The regex that Jasen sowed **is not** a BRE, as per definition a BRE has no alternation. It is an extension of POSIX BREs which also have alternation. But going from that idea to stating that there is an alternative BRE syntax for an alternation is impossible. There is no way to rewrite that (`(;|$)$`) without using alternation. @Kusalananda

Comment: But also, no, The regex was a bit more complex that what you wrote.  It was like `((X*(Y|$)){3})$` or `((something*(other|$)){3})$`. When `something*` match that something (once or several times) or (**the only other alternative**) the empty string the regex proceeds to match `other` or `end of line`. If what was matched was the `end of line (`$`) the regex stays at that position beetween the last character matched and the `end of line` without consuming the `end of line` marker. (Cont.)

Comment: (Cont.)  That is not equal to `(a|b)c` in that matching `b` that character is consumed by the regex engine. But here, yes, as an special case, the `$` is still present. But all that is allowed to match at that point are `empty strings` as no character is left between the last character and the `$`. If you want to write that in a loose naive way, it will be: `$` followed by `none, one, or several empty strings` followed by `$` again. So, also, no, `$$` is not equivalent to `$`.

Comment: @Isaac I don't understand quite what you're on about, but it feels as if we agree that the command that Jasen posted in their comment is not quite what I want to use.  You will also find that `$$` is indeed the same as `$` in an extended regular expression, i.e. anchoring to the end of the line. In a BRE, it matches an `$` character at the end of a line, but only if the final `$` of the expression is the last character of the expression.  These things are trivially tested (but I'd be very interested in an example that shows otherwise).